# 「source ~/.bash_profile」を実行すると「syntax error: unexpected end of file」と表示される

Tags: bash

表題の通り、Macのターミナルで「source ~/.bash_profile」を実行すると「syntax error: unexpected end of file」と表示されております。

ただ、viで.bash_profileを表示すると、下記の通り10行しかありません。

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fiexport PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

他サイトで解決法として提示されていたように行の位置を変更してみたり、色々いじってみたのですが、うまくいっておりません。
解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと見た感じ、3行目の

> ```
> fiexport PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
> ```

は

> ```
> fi
> export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
> ```

となるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、fiexportを
fi
export
としましたら解決いたしました。
初歩的なミスでお恥ずかしい限りです。
大変助かりました。
精進いたしますので、また何かありました際には何卒よろしくお願いいたします。